# Cannot respond the API call inside a call back function (in NodeJS request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, callback, request

I have this code in my NodeJS. If I put the return before the request.post call I get the response but inside the call back I get {data: null}.

```js
exports.addItem = functions.https.onCall((req, context)=>{
  request.post(
  {url: submitUrl,
  form: req},
  function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
          return {result: "OK"};
          }
      else{
        return {result: "Not OK"}
      }
      }
  );
});
```

if it helps, I run this code inside firebase and I am calling it with firebase functions in my JS

Comment: It's unclear what's the context for this code. But it looks like Express middleware. And if you want to send a response, call `res` directly.

Comment: How do you cal res directly?

Comment: What is `res`?  You didn't even confirm that it's Express. If it is then check the manual, https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Answer (score 0):

`return` will cause the function to end, but won't send anything to the user when it's an asynchronous callback like that. There is no calling function **that you control** for the value to be returned to.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but using a value with `return` in this context will result in the value being lost.

If you need to improve your understanding of the asynchronous callback idiom in Node.js, maybe check out https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/.

Comment: would it help if I use promises?

Answer (score 0):

You should use async/await to fix this issue

```
exports.addItem = functions.https.onCall(async (req, res)=>{
  await request.post(
  {url: submitUrl,
  form: req},
  function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
          return {result: "OK"};
          }
      else{
        return {result: "Not OK"}
      }
      }
  );
});
```